# How do I center my inputs in a div in HTML

Tags: html, css

I've been having an issue, my text box is at the very bottom of my div, I want it to be in the center, how can I fix this?

```
<input type="text" placeholder="search" id="search" name="search" required minlength="4" maxlength="90" size="75">
```

[How it Looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6kmw.png)

Comment: can you please provide the complete code

Comment: How is the containing div styled?

Answer (score 0):

Give your div a display flex property and use its aligning properties to align it according to your need.

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
```

Reply to this if you still face any issues. I will be happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```css
.inputbox {
background-color:red;
padding:15px;
display:flex;
justify-content:center;
align-items:center;
}

#search {
  text-align:center;
  //if you want center text also
}
```

```html
<div class="inputbox"><input type="text" placeholder="search" id="search" name="search" required minlength="4" maxlength="90" size="75"></div>
```